# Sending an email pdf attachment with PHP problems

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to make a script to send emails and attach pdfs or other types of files later on.

I have been following various tutorials and have come to a dead end.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code? I think i have just been looking at it for far too long.

```
<?php
    include ("../../includes/auth.php");

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $date = date('y-m-d h:i:s');

    $recipient = $_GET['email'];
    $lname = $_GET['lname'];
    $fname = $_GET['fname'];
    $subject ="Enquiry Form - $date";
    //-------------attachment stuff----------
    $fileatt = "/test.pdf";
    $fileatttype = "application/pdf";
    //$fileattname = "newname.pdf";
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    //-------------------------------------
    $headers = "From: test person <info@test.co.uk>";
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n".
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n".
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n".
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n". $message ."\n\n";
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "–-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    " filename=\"{$fileatt}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data . "\n\n" ."--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
    $message ."Dear ".$fname." ".$lname." Test message".$date;

    echo $recipient."<br />";
    echo $subject."<br />";
    echo $message."<br />";
    echo $headers."<br />";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);

    include ("../../includes/dbconn.php");

    $set_datesent = "UPDATE _leads SET `Covering_letter_sent` = '$date' WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
    //echo $set_datesent;
    $result = mysql_query ($set_datesent, $connection)
    or die ("Failed to perform query :  $sql <br />".mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: try giving the full path $fileatt = "/test.pdf";

Comment: Where do you specify what your problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use something like the [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) library. Then sending an attachment becomes as easy and readable as the code below. You'll have to make sure the Mail library is installed, but this is a fairly simple task.

```
require_once('Mail.php');
require_once('Mail/mime.php');

$text = wordwrap($message, 70); // You'd put the text version of your message here as $message

$mime = new Mail_Mime();
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setFrom($name . ' <' . $from_email . '>'); // The sender name and email ID go here
$mime->addAttachment($fpath, $ftype); // File path and type go here
$mime->setSubject($subject); // Subject goes here

$body = $mime->get()
$headers = $mime->headers();

$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
$mail->send($to_email, $headers, $body); // The recipients email address goes here

unset($mime, $mail);
```

Additional things also become much easier this way, for example, writing a HTML mail.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).  It's free and simplies your life by a lot.

Comment: There's [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) as well. both about equivalent in features/usability.

Comment: @webnet Hi can you help me with swiftmailer, i have written a script using the documentation and im just getting errors :( bad times.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest Pear Mail_mime package (http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/). I once did attachment handling by hand, because i didn't know such library exists (stupid me) and when i figured it out, i immediately got rid of my poorly made script and started to use Mail_mime. It has few glitches, but heck, it's so much easier than code it by hand.